# erro ao importar modulo

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse módulo num arquivo chamado timer.js

```
module.exports = {

    iniciar(){
        console.log('oi');
    }
}
```

Estou tentando importar este módulo no arquivo index.js da seguinte forma:

```
const timer = require('./timer');
```

só que está me retornando este erro:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './timer'
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mande um `tree` do seu diretorio principal

Comment: Desculpe, eu não sei o que é um tree rs.

Comment: Sua estrutura de arquivos, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-command-unixlinux/

Comment: Postei a imagem na pergunta

Comment: Seu código está no arquivo main.js?

Comment: Não, o arquivo que estou querendo exportar esta no timer.js e estou querendo importar no index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tem certeza que o time.js está no mesmo diretório?? Pois eu não localizei nenhum erro, e também não pode se esquecer que quando for chamada uma função deve-se colocar antes do nome da função o nome da variável que foi atribuído o require. Fiz duas formas de criar funções e colocar no exports, Veja esse exemplo:

Arquivo **main.js**

```
const timer = require('./timer');
timer.iniciar1();
timer.iniciar2();
```

Arquivo **timer.js**

```
const iniciar1 = () =>{
    console.log("oi 1");
};

module.exports = {
    iniciar1,
    iniciar2(){
        console.log("oi 2");
    },
};
```